# Custom external fan doesn't switch off when tablet is switched off

Tags: fan, tablet

I have an external fan which is connected via USB to a PC Portable tablet (Quaduro QuadPad 5016120).

When I switch off the tablet, the fan continues to run. If I take out the power supply, the fan stops.

I used the fan on my desktop PC and once switched off, the fan switches off.

Anyone know how to stop it (without pulling the plug)?

Answer (score 2):

Switch the USB port - it might be an always on port, used for charging devices when the system is on. Its often a different colour from the rest. You can often set this in bios, but switching USB ports might be easier.

Comment: tried switching usb but no sucess

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a power saving / USB charging setting most PC's would have in the BIOS.

Comment: Any settings in the BIOS?